# Selecting specific value in row of the selected checkbox and checking for duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I came across a problem whose solution has led me to post it here so others may make use of it or improvise better than me. 
My Problem: I have a table of results with check boxes to select rows. The requirement was to know if I was selecting(using the checkboxes) the same set of one particular column value, if so I had to do something.

Comment: Downvoted for no code in your question and voted to close for the same reason.

Comment: I am not sure why all questions should have a code in it. I have clearly mentioned this is more of a question with an answer I came across. so this forum does not encourage self found answers or what? Please educate me.

Comment: When you say `Problem: I have a table of results with check boxes to select rows. ` then you don't include the actual html, how does one solve the problem?  Without the problem *code* the question is very vague.  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

Considering the below being my html code for the dynamic table(CFML). The  tag has to be inside a loop to dynamically create the table content.

```
<table class="fixedTable">
 <thead class="containerbg">
   <tr class="listingheader">
      <td>StagingID</td>
      <td>BatchID</td>
      <td>AuditID</td>
      <td>Action</td>
      <td>File Name</td>
      <td>Card No</td>
      <td>Card No</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="cur_row" >
    <td>#staging_id#</td>
    <td>#batch_import_job_id#</td>
    <td>#audit_Id#</td>
    <td>#code#</td>
    <td class="file_name">#source_filename#</td>
    <td>#card_number#</td>
    <td class="tblResolve">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass cb"  name="resolveErrorsCheck" value="#row_no#">
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS Code

```
  //register the click event

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '.cb',enableDisableActions);

 });

  function enableDisableActions() {
var values = new Array(); 
           $.each($("input[name='resolveErrorsCheck']:checked").closest('td').siblings('.file_name'),
             function (){
                  values.push($(this).text());
             });
            const initial = values[0];      
            const result = values.filter(src => src != initial);
            if(result.length){
               //no duplicate file_name selected
               //do something
            }else{
                //duplicate file_name selected
                //do something
            }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the body and table closing tags in your HTML. Also in your $.each call there is no .on("click", function()....it just has function()

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  If this is suppose to be in your question, click the edit button on the question to include relevant code.  [Stack Overflow is not a Forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum).